# Installing rails. Gem install rails stucks (for real!), and curl stucks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rubygems

:)

I am trying to install ruby on rails on VirtualBox. I started with Fedora... without success, now I am giving Ubuntu a try, and still some problems occur. I wrote:

```
$ gem install rails
$ gem -V install rails
$ gem update --system
```

I waited... but nothing happend. Then i tried diffrent approach and I wanted to install RVM... but then

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

stucked... It downloaded 1 file... and that was it.

Any hint?
oh... to install ruby on rails i followed this way:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
$ wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.8.24.tgz
$ tar zxvf rubygems-1.8.24.tgz
$ cd rubygems-1.8.24
$ sudo ruby setup.rb
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
$ gem install rails
```

And I can't go any further than this...

Answer (score 0):

Try using rbenv instead of rvm, bit simpler for a start.
rbenv + ruby-build is a must ;)

```
rbenv install ruby
gem install bundler
gem install rails
```

Maybe your OS has already a ruby installed and its interfering...
try :

```
which ruby
```

to find out.

Can't tell you more without nknowing more. :s
Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for reply but still problem is unsolved. I wrote sudo apt-get install rbenv rbenv install ruby and an error occured rbenv: no such commend install
and when i wrote which ruby
`/usr/bin/ruby`
But i want o install rails not ruby.... ruby works fine :)

Comment: did you add the commands in your .bashrc given by the rbenv documentation ?
what does which rbenv return ?